# Can we put getters and setters in abstract classes..?

Tags: java

```
public abstract ClassName
{

 // methods
 // setters & getters...???

}
```

Comment: It would have taken you 30 seconds to find out. It would either compile or not.

Comment: Thanks Oded well i'm a beginner you have to take it easy ;)

Comment: @W M - It is just lazy to ask something like that instead of trying. You have a compiler - if you want to know if something like this is possible, try it. The compiler will complain if it is not valid. If will be faster for you and you will learn something in the process.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The short answer: yes:

```
public abstract class ClassName {
    private String field;

    public String getString() {
        return field;
    }

    public void setString(String field) {
        this.field = field;
    }
}
```

More extended answer (I'm not sure that it's actual for you right now):

You should realize that these methods (if they are not declared with `final` modifier) can be overriden in subclasses. That's why it's important to think about methods contracts and document them carefully. If one of the methods of your abstract class invokes another its method then this fact should also be documented.

All protected and public methods (and constants, and in very very seldom cases - protected fields) of your abstract class become a part of your API. Thus, other developers can use them and it's not very easy to change them.

About best practices:

1) Think twice before making your class `Serializable` - this will make all subclasses searializable too and (if you want to produce not potentially broken program) you should care about possible serialization of any of the subclasses.

2) The same is actual for implementing `Cloneable` (do not better implement it in a top-level abstract class).

3) You should provide correct `equals` and `hashCode` implementation taking into account that 2 subclasses can be compared with *your* implementation from the abstract class.

4) Think about providing natural ordering (i.e. implementing `Comparable` interface). It's often a good idea if there is a real natural ordering exists.

Comment: just curious, should be it done that way? I mean, any java best practices?

Comment: Of course, why not? field belongs to ClassName. In fact, since it's private, it's the only possible place for a getter/setter.

Comment: There's no reason why you shouldn't do this.  An abstract class is simply a class where some behavior is deferred to concrete subclass implementations.  However, other aspects of the class (e.g. certain properties) could still be legitimately defined (with appropriate getters and setters).  The question as to whether instance variables should remain private in the superclass is probably contentious - My preferred style is to make them protected and to access them directly in the subclass.  My rationale for this is that if the superclass requires refactoring the subclass probably will too.

Answer (score -4):

Guys Of course Implementing an abstract type modifier getter() would result in compilation error!